# Should we get rid of the [experience] tag?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

With the recent changes, perhaps we should discuss and vote about this question?

Feel free to improve vote answers (those that start with a bold sentence) or add new ones.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it's useful to have this as a normal/meta tag, because of one of the following reasons:**

- The [6-Q guidelines](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice) aren't there to enforce questions to be about [experience].
- *Feel free to add reasons here, discuss these in the comments.*

Comment: It's a misconception (including me) about the 6 guidelines. They're not the heart of Pr.SE. If I'm not misunderstanding again, of course :-) See more: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-types-of-subjective-questions-are-not-acceptable/380#380

Comment: Although I'm unable to vote I'm also in for this answer... But then it should probably be modified to focus less on the experience part but yet be useful for the community. Please note that I have commented on that answer before this one, don't take it too literal... Don't take it personal either, you're doing fine as a moderator. :-)

Comment: Accepting this one, it's a misconception... If anyone reasonably disagrees, he can repost this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, most questions will be about experience thanks to [the 6-Q enforcement notice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice).**

Answer (score -3):

**No, it isn't useful to have this meta tag, because:**

- *Feel free to add reasons here, discuss these in the comments.*