# I don't think people (or me) understand programmers.se

Tags: discussion, questions, moderators, vote-to-close

I trully understand when a question is unproper for a site, but this is ridiculous.

My question was ['Do you have a phone on your desk?'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/do-you-have-a-phone-on-your-desk-closed). Obviously my intent was to share experiences from fellow programmers. It is not about some error in my code, it is about a programmer's daily work.

I believe my question follows some of [Jeff Atwood' Six Subjective Question Guidelines](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice)

Am I that wrong? Am I missing something? My question got 17 answers and some up votes in those answers, one of them from a deaf guy, which I believe is pretty interesting.

Can anybody please explain why people closed that question?

Comment: I guess one question is: Could the question have been rephrased to make it "constructive" in the eyes of the mod team?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I totally not understand the point of Programmers.SE?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/360/do-i-totally-not-understand-the-point-of-programmers-se)

Comment: Ha, I voted to close this.  I think it's the first thing I ever voted to close.  Anyway, I completely sympathize with you and I'm certain that if every question that I ask is closed and every question that I answer is closed that eventually I'm going to get sick of this website.   The only reason I voted to close the question is because Mr. C gave a much better answer than that Robert Cartaino guy could ever give you.

Comment: Don't we all have phones in our pockets?  Is this question out of 1995?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have provided some context to make it a decent question. I'll admit, at first glance, this *sounds* like a really silly, nonsensical question. It might as well read *"how many people have all their teeth?"* Who the h— cares?

But now that you expound on the question here, I started thinking about it: "Wow, that really *is* an interesting question. Is it a distraction? Does it enhance productivity? Advantages, disadvantages? Can we do without it altogether?" If you spent an extra minute formulating the question, adding a bit of context or clarifying what you were asking, maybe it wouldn't have come off as so flip and pointless.

Let's chalk it up to "decent question, poorly asked."

Comment: +1 Robert, I agree it is not well formulated now that I read it again

Comment: And it can be reopen if it be written in a constructive way.