# What if I can't reasonably accept a single answer to a question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, guidelines

After reviewing the '[Great Redisiplining](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice)' and learning that we now *do* accept answers here, I'm not sure how I should handle accepting some of my previous questions. I have only asked a few, but some of them do not have have specific 'right' answer. For example, '[Do you work contract projects in addition to your full-time job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10495/do-you-work-contract-projects-in-addition-to-your-full-time-job)' and '[What features are missing from the languages you use?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/634/what-features-are-missing-from-the-languages-you-use)' are open-ended forum-type questions that have produced valuable discussion, but there is no correct response which should be accepted.

On a related note, one of my first questions-
[Good furniture for programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/742/good-furniture-for-programmers), although rather popular, almost certainly does not fit here under the new guidelines; should it be closed?

For the questions above and perhaps similar ones like it by other members, what is the correct course of action and are they still permissible here under the new guidelines?

### Edit

The chief concern here is that we have chosen not to hide the accept rate from profiles, so I don't really wish to be toting around a badge that says '0% Accept Rate' if it is going to have an adverse affect on my standing.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to accept an answer, particularly on Programmers.

However, there are various options open to you (assuming that you have two answers of equal merit).

1. Upvote A (10 rep) but accept B (15 rep)
2. Upvote A (10 rep), upvote B (10 rep) but don't accept any answer.
3. Upvote and accept A (25 rep) and award a bounty to B (min 50 rep).
4. and so on.

You are only limited by your imagination.

In response to your update - I don't really consider people's accept rate even on Stack Overflow so it will be even less of an issue here.

If people do start commenting on accept rate, then it becomes an issue we need to discuss.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Meta Stack Overflow FAQ on accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):

> #### Which answer should I choose?
>
> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - It is generally accepted that you should wait 24 to 48 hours to let a bunch of people have a chance to answer your question. A question with an accepted answer may deter people from looking at a question.
> - Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack.
> - **The bottom line is to accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.**