# How to determine which answer is most correct

Tags: discussion, answers

My question, if there is [...a canonical way to format 'usage' output for a cli script?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/441932/is-there-a-canonical-way-to-format-usage-output-for-a-cli-script) has two good answers. [One](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/441942/422305) addresses the question posed, but the [other](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/441933/422305) addresses my specific use case presented earlier in the question (answer for python).

Should I edit my question to be more specific?

Which answer is more correct? (and therefore set as the accepted answer)

Comment: Maybe this former meta post helps you? [What if I can't reasonably accept a single answer to a question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-if-i-cant-reasonably-accept-a-single-answer-to-a-question).

Comment: (... and I am not voting to close as a duplicate, since we are here on meta where I think people should get a chance to get specific answers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is completely up to you to which answer you give your mark, just pick the one which suits you best, the one of which you think it will help the community most, or the one you like most - noone else except you can make this decision. You can also leave your question with no accepted answer, if you cannot make a decision, or wait with accepting for several weeks or months, if you don't want to make a decision now.

Concerning the two answers, IMHO none of them is "more correct" than the other - one is more specific, the other one more general, but both correct, so it is perfectly ok when you just pick one of them at will, or none, or just wait.

Of course, when one accepts a blatantly wrong answer to a question, expect the community to start a discussion about it. But they will usually aim at the wrong answer, not the asker. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer) for more information on such cases.