# Introduction to new community moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

you may be familiar with me, but in case you aren't I am maple_shaft and I was asked to be the new community moderator.  I am very excited to take this responsibility and I hope that I do not let anyone down.  I believe in the purpose and scope of Programmers and wish to help guide it in the right direction going forward.

Some of you may have noticed that Mark Trapp decided to step down, [No more "Chairman Mao reincarnate" :(](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/no-more-chairman-mao-reincarnate)

I wish the circumstances were different, and I want it to be said that I feel that I couldn't ever replace his true role here.  I would be an awful replacement if that were the case, but the wealth of information he provided on Meta is a guiding step so that I can at least benefit from his years of experience in this role.

If any of you have any questions for me, about me, or just want to offer some help or guidance then please do.  I look forward to working closely with the users of the site to make this a better place for all.

`<joke>` With that being said, I intend to rule with an iron fist.  All infractions of the FAQ will be met with swift and brutal punishment.  Users will bow before my might.  I have the power!
[image]
`</joke>`

Kidding aside I am pretty jovial and personable too!  I look forward to getting to know you all better in chat!

Comment: Welcome to team diamond! Looking forward to working with you...

Comment: ["Who is the best moderator **for Programmers**?"](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/community-perception-of-programmers-se-the-stackoverflow-landfill/2973#comment7560_2973)

Comment: Welcome aboard.

Comment: Welcome to the team.

Comment: So instead of being trapped, bad questions shall be shafted?

Comment: @WorldEngineer I figured that I owe an explanation for my user name. Many have been curious if I were a "gifted" Canadian man to which I will state that I am not.  I am from the United States and I play billiards. I first used this name over a decade ago on an online pool game and it references my maple shaft pool cue.

Comment: @WorldEngineer I'm leery of puns like that.

Comment: I voted for you maple_shaft. I'm glad that you were next in line.

Comment: Welcome maple_shaft!! Excellent community choice

Comment: @maple_shaft: i was thinking `maple -> wood/hard`; `shaft -> [...]`

Comment: Nice to see a picture of you at last! For some reason the picture I envisioned when I saw your name was that of a big baby-blue maple leaf (no idea where I got that from), and I have to say, your picture doesn't make you look anything like that :)

Comment: @Rachel Thanks, this is rare for me, because I greatly value my anonymity.  TBH I am still not that comfortable labeling my common internet presence to my mugshot because I am paranoid that my boss will stumble across my profile on a Google search and see some of my "gripes" and "disagreements" posted online.  Not sure how long I will keep this picture on my profile.  I will probably change it eventually to a baby-blue maple leaf ;)

Answer (score 3):

#### Welcome!

I wasn't a user back when the elections where held, but our [first ever discussion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4117/51770) today was certainly pleasant and informative, what I'd expect from a moderator.

<sub>This "question" remained "unanswered" for far too long!</sub>